# How to match two values in dict and merge results

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Say I have some data with timestamps, prices and amounts.  This data can be quite large and matching conditions could occur anywhere in the group.  A simple example shown below:

```
[{"date":1387496043,"price":19.379,"amount":1.000000}
{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":2.00000}
{"date":1387496044,"price":10.00,"amount":0.10000}
{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":0.300000}]
```

How could I sort this so I combine the amounts of any item that has the same timestamp and same price?

So the results look like (note the 2.0 and 0.3 amounts have been summed together):

```
[{"date":1387496043,"price":19.379,"amount":1.000000}
{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":2.30000}
{"date":1387496044,"price":10.00,"amount":0.10000}]
```

I've tried a number of convoluted methods (using Python 2.7.3), but I don't know python very well.  I'm sure there's a good way to find 2 matching values and then updating one with new amount and removing the duplicate.

FYI Here is the test data

```
L=[{"date":1387496043,"price":19.379,"amount":1.000000},{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":2.00000},{"date":1387496044,"price":10.00,"amount":0.10000},{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":0.300000}]
```

Comment: What do you want to sort by? date? price?

Also, in the example you don't combine (add?) but filter out duplicates. Is that what you want?

Comment: From your sql query it looks like you understand.  I'm combining amounts on all items that have same timestamp and price into one item and then removing the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this would be to make a dictionary with (date, price) as keys.  If you ever encounter a duplicate key, you can combine your fields to keep the keys unique.

```
def combine(L):
    results = {}
    for item in L:
        key = (item["date"], item["price"])
        if key in results:  # combine them
            results[key] = {"date": item["date"], "price": item["price"], "amount": item["amount"] + results[key]["amount"]}
        else:  # don't need to combine them
            results[key] = item
    return results.values()
```

This would be a slightly messy O(n) solution to your example that can obviously be generalized to solve your initial problem.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using 2.7.3.  I see what you're doing, but being new to python.  I don't get the syntax.  key = (item[["date"], item["price"]) produces a syntax error.

Comment: Funny, I didn't see that either.  I've run into the same error I get when I've tried a couple of things on my own:  key = (item["date"], item["price"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: If I do a print type(L) I get <type 'list'>.  The list in my data does contain a few more keys:values but those should be ignored right?

Comment: It would be nice to see the actual data you're using.  When I input something similar to your example using Python 2.7.5, everything works as expected.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something basic wrong.  But I put the test data as shown into the question.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written python in too long...
I've updated it to fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

A defaultdict-based approach

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(float)
z = [{"date":1387496043,"price":19.379,"amount":1.000000},
{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":2.00000},
{"date":1387496044,"price":10.00,"amount":0.10000},
{"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":0.300000}]
for x in z:
    d[x["date"], x["price"]] += x["amount"]
print [{"date": k1, "price": k2, "amount": v} for (k1, k2), v in d.iteritems()] 
[{'date': 1387496044, 'price': 10.0, 'amount': 0.1},
{'date': 1387496044, 'price': 20.2, 'amount': 2.3},
{'date': 1387496043, 'price': 19.379, 'amount': 1.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW you can do it using database operations:

```
records = [
    {"date":1387496043,"price":19.379,"amount":1.000000},
    {"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":2.00000},
    {"date":1387496044,"price":10.00,"amount":0.10000},
    {"date":1387496044,"price":20.20,"amount":0.300000},
]

import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
db.execute('CREATE TABLE records (date int, price float, amount float)')
db.executemany('INSERT INTO records VALUES (:date, :price, :amount)', records)
sql = 'SELECT date, price, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM records GROUP BY date, price'
records = [dict(row) for row in db.execute(sql)]
print(records)
```

Comment: Oh my... Are you joking? :D

Comment: It's not a bad idea if I was starting with a database already.